# Maven / Apache wdsl2code generated classes are hidden for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-axis

I'm trying to generate classes from a wsdl.

The generation process seems ok, but I'm facing some classpath problems.

I'm able to browse the generated classes, but eclipse is unable to see some of them :

- target/myservice : ok
- target/classes : I don't know why axis plugin generates some classes here ; I can browse there but eclipse is unable to see this folder

I've tried to add a source folder manually, wihout success..

Axis plugin config :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate 1</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <packageName>com.stuff</packageName>
                        <wsdlFile>${basedir}/myservice.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        <databindingName>adb</databindingName>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>target/mysservice</outputDirectory>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

`axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin` doesn't generate anything under `target/classes`; `maven-compiler-plugin` produces those files. To make the generated sources visible in Eclipse, add `target/mysservice/src` as a source folder.